# dynamic changing max range and document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rangeslider

I have a range slider and I want the `max` range to be set dynamically from the html text of a `div` with `class="aaa"`. unfortunately it doesn't not work. And maybe I have some error in the `var = zzz` that sets the max value..

Here's my code

```js
var  zzz = document.getElementById('aaa').val();   
document.getElementById('slider1').max = zzz;  

const $mutuo = $("#mutuo"),
  $rata = $("#rata"),
  $anni = $("#anni"),
  $slider1 = $("#slider1"),
  $slider2 = $("#slider2"),
  $max = $("#aaa").html();


function showAmount1(newAmount){
    document.getElementById('mutuo').innerHTML = newAmount;     
    $mutuo.val($("#mutuo").innerHTML);
    update();
}


function showAmount2(newAmount){

    document.getElementById('anni').innerHTML = newAmount; 
    $anni.val($("#anni").innerHTML);
    update();
}
    
    



  function update() {
  let interesseannuo = 1.60,
    C = $mutuo.html(),
    anni = $anni.html(),
    i = interesseannuo / 12 / 100,
    n = anni * 12,
    rata = C * i / (1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n));

  $rata.html(rata.toFixed(2) + " €");
}
update();
```

```html
<div class="info-text-wrapper">
    <p  class="info-paragraph black" val="123456" id="aaa">123456</p>
    <p  class="info-paragraph black">Totale mutuo (€)</p>
     <input type="range" min="0" max="" value="" step="10" onchange="showAmount1(this.value)" id="slider1"/>

    <div class="info-paragraph black" type="text" id="mutuo" >10000</div><br><br><br>

    <p class="info-paragraph black">Durata mutuo (anni)</p>
    <input type="range" min="10" max="30" value="10" step="5" onchange="showAmount2(this.value)" id="slider2">
    <div class="info-paragraph black" type="text" id="anni" >10</div><br><br><br>

    <p class="info-paragraph black">La tua rata</p>
    <div class="paragraph" id="rata"></div><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val()` is used in jQuery, For javascript you need to use `value`

In javascript if you want the input value then use

```
document.getElementById('aaa').value
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById('aaa').val()
```

If you want text of element you can use

```
document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('aaa').innerText
```

```js
var zzz = document.getElementById('aaa').innerText;
document.getElementById('slider1').max = zzz;

const $mutuo = $("#mutuo"),
        $rata = $("#rata"),
        $anni = $("#anni"),
        $slider1 = $("#slider1"),
        $slider2 = $("#slider2"),
        $max = $("#aaa").html();

function showAmount1(newAmount) {
 document.getElementById('mutuo').innerHTML = newAmount;
 $mutuo.val($("#mutuo").innerHTML);
 update();
}

function showAmount2(newAmount) {
 document.getElementById('anni').innerHTML = newAmount;
 $anni.val($("#anni").innerHTML);
 update();
}

function update() {
 let interesseannuo = 1.60,
         C = $mutuo.html(),
         anni = $anni.html(),
         i = interesseannuo / 12 / 100,
         n = anni * 12,
         rata = C * i / (1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n));

 $rata.html(rata.toFixed(2) + " €");
}
update();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-text-wrapper">
    <p  class="info-paragraph black" val="123456" id="aaa">123456</p>
    <p  class="info-paragraph black">Totale mutuo (€)</p>
     <input type="range" min="0" max="" value="" step="10" onchange="showAmount1(this.value)" id="slider1"/>
    <div class="info-paragraph black" type="text" id="mutuo" >10000</div><br><br><br>
    <p class="info-paragraph black">Durata mutuo (anni)</p>
    <input type="range" min="10" max="30" value="10" step="5" onchange="showAmount2(this.value)" id="slider2">
    <div class="info-paragraph black" type="text" id="anni" >10</div><br><br><br>
    <p class="info-paragraph black">La tua rata</p>
    <div class="paragraph" id="rata"></div><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

val() function only fetches the value of input elements. In order to get the text of  other elements, you need to use innerHTML or innerText. Just replace

```
var  zzz = document.getElementById('aaa').val();
```

with

```
var  zzz = document.getElementById('aaa').innerText;
```

It should work.

Comment: This suggestion is ok if the div content it is not dynamic. But if the div innerText is dynamically generate it does not work.. for that I had to wrap that part into a `$(document).ready funcion()`
But ,now I've another problem.. if you see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhw3sf4d/9/) the structure of the page is more complex and i want that, when I click on those ugly grey buttons, the price changes dynamically and even the slider `max`.. Is this possible?
Can i contact you directly? maybe is more simple to understand...